# Fast travel in the Witcher

Tags: the-witcher

Is there a "fast travel" feature in the Witcher (enhanced edition)? I could not find any by clicking on the map, but it would be really useful sometimes.

Comment: @Jerome wrong game, but ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no fast travel in the Witcher, even in the enhanced edition.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is some sort of although heavily limited. Without spoilering: At least for some time you can use Places of Power to get back to a house in the city. Furthermore you can later use several teleporter places throughout the world although you can only travel from one teleporter to the other.

Comment: Actually your post should be marked as the answer. :)